# Hide all elements from screen readers except one div?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I have implemented a popup that is triggered from a button on my webpage. This popup nearly fills the entire screen and prevents users from interacting with anything on the webpage until the popup is dismissed. This works well for sighted users, but when using VoiceOver on the Mac you can still navigate the underlying web page content, and the blind user would have no idea a popup window was presented.

How can I prevent VoiceOver from navigating every element on the page except for one `div` (and every element in that `div`)?

I know one can use `aria-hidden="true"` to hide it from screen readers, and I know one can force a focus on an element, but I'm not sure how best to accomplish this. Do I need to loop over the entire DOM and essentially hide everything then upon close unhide everything? Or is there a better approach, some ARIA property that defines this type of element that's presented perhaps?

A website that exhibits the desired behavior is [Piazza](http://piazza.com). When you activate the Login button it presents a popup modal dialog and demands focus, and you can't navigate away from it until you dismiss the popup.

Comment: aria-hidden indicates that the element and all of its descendants are not visible, so you do not have to loop entire DOM

Comment: please add your modal implementation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implementing accessible modal dialogs correctly has got to be one of the trickier aspects of web accessibility, since there's just *so many* things to watch out for, on top of the usual issues of screenreader and browser compat and adherence to spec. Here's a summary(!), somewhat based on personal experience, [this article from Smashing Magazine on accessible Modal dialogs](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/15/making-modal-windows-better-for-everyone/), [WAI-ARIA 1.0 Authoring Best Practices](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#dialog_modal) and [this slideshow on the same topic](http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/accessible-modal-windows).

(Note that you'll find some conflicting advice between these; this is somewhat due to differences in behavior between screenreaders/browsers and spec, and different authors having different positions on whether to stick to spec vs work with the screenreaders that real users actually use.)

- Tell screenreaders it's a dialog: Add role="dialog" to the parent DIV, and set aria-labelledby to point to the ID of the title.

  This causes the screenreader to recognize the piece of UI as a dialog in the first place; when the user navigates into it, either by navigating or because focus moves into it, the screenreader will announce that the user is now in a dialog, and will likely also announce the title. (On some screenreader/browser combinations - notably VoiceOver+Safari, it may also affect how screenreader navigation works.) This alone does not 'hide' any of the other UI on the page, however.
- Add basic keyboard support

  There's a bunch of things to do here that are important for both screenreader users and non-screenreader using keyboard users. Two key issues here are to move focus to somewhere appropriate in the  the dialog when it initially appears, and when the dialog is dismissed, restore focus back to where it was when the dialog originally appeared.
- Make it modal for screenreader users and keyboard users

  Dialogs come in two flavors: modal, which don't let the user interact with any other UI while present, and modeless, which do let the user leave the dialog and return later - examples might be the "Find Text" dialogs in some text editors. role="dialog" doesn't distinguish between these two cases, and also using ARIA doesn't have any affect on browser behavior, so if your dialog is modal, you have to do extra work yourself to make it behave as modal. There's two aspects to this:

  - Just as modal dialogs use a gray scrim or blur effect to visually hide the inactive background from sighted users, we also want to hide this content from screenreader users: otherwise they will still be able to navigate out of the dialog to the background, or use other hotkeys to list links or headings or other controls from the page and will see both items from the background part of the page and the dialog. In the past, putting aria-hidden="true" on all other top-level DIVs was the best tool to use to do this (and a bit fiddly - remember to remove it when done!), but as of 2020, [aria-modal="true"](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-modal) appears to be decently supported and is much easier to implement.
  - For both screenreader users and non-screenreader-using keyboard users, you also need to make the keyboard behavior modal: hitting tab from the last item in the dialog should wrap to the top of the dialog, and the inverse behavior for shift-tab. If you don't do this, keyboard - and screenreader - users can simply tab right out of your dialog into the background of the page. There's different approaches for doing this, most involve tracking focusin or similar at the body level, and forcing focus back into the dialog if it "escapes".
- Other tweaks/fixes/hacks

  Windows-based screenreaders such as NVDA and JAWS go into "application mode" when they enter a dialog:  their web navigation hotkeys no longer work, and they treat the content of the dialog as a form rather than a rich web page. This is fine is the dialog content is a classic form with just fields, labels and buttons, but isn't a good fit if the dialog contains web content with text, hyperlinks, and the like. In that case, you might want to place a `<div role="document">...</div>` within your role="dialog" but wrapping the main content.
- Ensure dialog content is itself accessible

  Should go without saying, but all of the above counts for nothing unless the content within the dialog is itself accessible.
- Most importantly: understand why you are making the dialog accessible in the first place, and test appropriately.

  Unfortunately, at the moment (Jan 2015!) there's still a lot of variation in behavior between different screenreaders (also depending in browser used); it's almost like how browsers were with CSS a decade(!) or so ago. It's worth understanding why you want to make your UI accessible, figure out where most of your users are going to be, and test appropriately given the screenreaders they'll be using. From [the most recent (Jan 2014) WebAim Screenreader survey](http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey5/#used), Windows readers - notably JAWS and NVDA - have the majority of the market, with VoiceOver coming third.

  Here's one possible strategy to consider:

  - If you just want to do a basic 'due diligence', then testing with just VoiceOver may be fine. The experience may not be as good on the other screenreaders, but if something works with VO, it's likely not going to be completely broken on the others.
  - Next level up is to get a copy of (free, but feel free to donate) [NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/) windows-based screenreader and run it in a VM on a Mac (assuming you're using a Mac here). NVDA and JAWS tend to be pretty close behavior-wise.
  - If accessibility is part of your job description, then likely you or your company will need to get a copy of [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS) ($800+!), since that appears to be the screenreader of choice for government and educational institutions. (This is perhaps the accessibility analog of testing with downlevel versions of IE!)

Comment: This is a lot of good info. Too bad it doesn't "just work." Thanks for the links as well!

Comment: Ya, dialogs are a whole hella mess, IMO. HTML5 was planned to have a `dialog` tag that might do much of this automatically - [but alas it seems to have been dropped for now](http://html5doctor.com/a-little-more-conversation-with-dialog/). BTW, some frameworks (eg JQueryUI?) may do much of the above for you automatically; may be a better approach than rolling your own support.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through all the top level items and set aria-hidden=true on those items. This is an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>aria-hidden examples</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a aria-hidden="true" href="#">Link at top</a>
        <p aria-hidden="true">Lots of text content</p>
        <form aria-hidden="true">
            <label for="input">Label</label>
            <input id="input" type="text" />
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div>
            <label for="dialogInput">Nother Label</label>
            <input id="dialogInput" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <form aria-hidden="true">
            <label for="input2">Label 2</label>
            <input id="input2" type="text" />
            <button>Submit 2</button>
        </form>
        <a aria-hidden="true" href="#">Link at bottom</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that this will cause the announcements to stay within the "dialog", but if you press the tab key, the focus can move outside the dialog and not get announced. This means that if there are interactive elements outside the dialog, the user could end up interacting with the wrong elements. Other browsers will do similar things.

So you will need to trap the focus inside the dialog using a Javascript event handler to handle your TAB keys if your page includes other naturally focusable elements like in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

WAI-ARIA provides the [dialog](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#dialog) and [alertdialog](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#alertdialog) roles to define dialogs. The dialog role is used when the user is expected to provide data, and the alertdialog role is used to announce the contents of a dialog to the user.

**Alert dialog**

```
<div role="alertdialog"
     aria-labelledby="dlgtitle"
     aria-describedby="instructions">
  <h1 id="dlgtitle">Shutdown instructions</h1>
  <ol id="instructions">
    <li>Open timesheet</li>
    <li>Enter time for today</li>
    <li>Close all open applications</li>
    <li>Shut down system</li>
  </ol>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="OK">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Dialog**

```
<div role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dlgtitle">
  <h1 id="dlgtitle">Sign up to Newsletter</h1>
  <ol id="instructions">
    <li>Enter email address</li>
    <li>Press the 'Sign up' button</li>
    <li>You're all signed up!</li>
  </ol>
  <div>
    <label for="email">Email: </label>
    <input type="text" 
           id="email"
           name="email"
           aria-describedby="instructions">
    <input type="button" value="Sign up">
  </div>
</div>
```

[**WAI-ARIA Authoring practice design pattern for a modal dialog**](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#dialog_modal)

Comment: These do _not_ hide the other elements, though; you have to use aria-hidden for that.

Comment: The need of OP is prevent VoiceOver from navigating every element on the page except modal, WAI-ARIA 1.0 Authoring Practices suggest dialog and alert-dialog to achieve this task

Comment: I think you're misreading the docs; role=dialog does let the reader know that that portion of the UI is a self-contained dialog - not necessarilly modal, however; and as a result, does not prevent the user navigating outside, either by keyboard tabbing _or_ navigating. (This is also my experience of using ARIA on modal dialogs, testing against VoiceOver, JAWS and NVDA, so my comment here is based both on spec and RL experience). If you want to prevent a screenreader from accessing content, aria-hidden is the way to do that; for a modal dialog impl, you need to use *both* techniques.

Comment: FWIW, the ARIA authoring practices are often useful, but tend to be incomplete, or don't take real world behavior into account; think of them perhaps more as aspiration rather than descriptive. [This article on accessible modal dialogs from Smashing Magazing](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/15/making-modal-windows-better-for-everyone/) has a better run-down of the issues involved, including use of both role and aria-hidden.

Comment: @BrendanMcK please add your answer

Comment: @BrendanMcK After setting `role="dialog"` AND manually changing focus to an item inside the dialog, VoiceOver indeed does not allow you to focus anything outside of the dialog. If you don't manually focus then you can still interact with anything on the page.

Comment: @Joey; what's actually happening here is that VoiceOver+Safari (but not VoiceOver+Chrome - and AFAIK not any of the other major screenreader/browser combinations) treat content within role="dialog" as a separate section; Ctrl+Option+Arrow will stop at the end as you note, but the user can navigate to the parent container - the web page - using Shift+Ctrl+Option+Up (or +Down to navigate back in); this is standard VO navigation for navigating composite items, do it again on the web page and you can then navigate the browser UI.

Comment: @BrendanMcK I see that behavior now. You can indeed step up through the "hierarchy" to get out of the dialog. That might be ok, at least in this case, though perhaps not ideal. Hmm